# How do you use the mapped value?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, dictionary, polymorphism

I have a mapping of

```
map <ShapeType, vector <Shape *> > shapeMap;
```

And I insert random shapes into the map. 
I want to use the method(Draw) for the mapped value.  How do you go about doing that, when I traverse through the map?

```
void RandomAttributes(Shape *shape);

// declare our objects, and pointers for downcasting
MyRect rObj, *rPtr;
MyTriangle tObj, *tPtr;
MyCircle cObj, *cPtr;



void main()
{
    int shapes; // loop index

    // seed the random number generator
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    // allow the user time to move the console window away
    // from the FilledShapes window are
    cout << "Move this window to the lower right of the screen, and press ENTER to continue:\n";
    cin.get();



    // define our array size
    const int baseSize = 3;

    // create an vector of base class pointers
    vector <Shape *> baseShape(baseSize);

    // initialize our vector of base class pointers
    //initialize vector of shapes
    baseShape[0] = &rObj; // a MyRect IS A Shape
    baseShape[1] = &tObj;   // a MyTriangle IS A Shape
    baseShape[2] = &cObj; // a MyCircle IS A Shape

    enum ShapeType {
        MyRectangle = 0,
        MyTriangle = 1,
        MyCircle = 2
    };

    //map
    map <ShapeType, vector <Shape *> > shapeMap;


    for (int i = 0; i<PROGRAM_RUN; i++)
    {
        // clear the window
        // note that I can use ANY instance of a MyRect
        // object to clear the window
        baseShape[0]->ClearScreen();

        int rNum = rand() % 3;

        //CREATING RANDOM SHAPES
        // choose random parameters for each rectangle
        RandomAttributes(baseShape[rNum]);

        //insert shape
        shapeMap.insert(pair<ShapeType, vector <Shape *>>(ShapeType(rNum), baseShape)) ;

    }

    for (map <ShapeType, vector <Shape *> >::iterator pos = shapeMap.begin(); pos != shapeMap.end(); ++pos)
    {
       //DOES NOT WORK
        pos->second->Draw();
    }

}
```

My current implementation:

```
    for (map <ShapeType, vector <Shape *> >::iterator pos = shapeMap.begin(); pos != shapeMap.end(); ++pos)
    {
       //DOES NOT WORK
        pos->second->Draw();
    }

}
```

How do I traverse through the map and use the draw method as follows:
mapped values I want to implement as follows:

```
//baseShape[0]->Draw();
//baseShape[1]->Draw();
//baseShape[2]->Draw();
```

If my datatype of the map is baseShape vector pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose doesn't work because `pos->second` isn't a `Shape*`, it's a `vector<Shape*`>. You have to iterate over that second one too:

```
for (map <ShapeType, vector <Shape *> >::iterator pos = shapeMap.begin(); 
     pos != shapeMap.end(); ++pos)
{
    vector<Shape*>& shapes = pos->second;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < shapes.size(); ++i) {
        shapes[i]->Draw();
    }
}
```

Or if you can use C++11:

```
for (auto& pr : shapeMap) {
    for (auto shape : pr.second) {
        shape->Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the proper implementation of inserting an item to the map?
  shapeMap.insert(pair<ShapeType, vector <Shape *>>(ShapeType(rNum), baseShape)) ;
More specifically (ShapeType(rNum).
Because when I print out the counter of the outer loop, I only get 3 when I should be getting 20 (PROGRAM_RUN = 20).

Comment: @user2577345 Syntactically it's correct, but you only have 3 different keys in your map (`MyRectangle`, `MyTriangle`, `MyCircle`). `map` can only have one value for each key... hence you only have 3 items. Either you need more keys or if you're ok with having multiple values for each key, use `multi_map`.

Comment: I used a multimap and inserted everything like you said. However when I output the mapped values, I get the same 3 shapes in the same area iterating through one at a time. Am I not properly inserting the items? here:  shapeMap.insert(pair<ShapeType, vector <Shape *>>(ShapeType(rNum), baseShape)) ; I could have 20 MyCircle ShapeType, but only 1 of them is repeatedly outputting.

Comment: Well you're inserting the same vector every time. If you want different shapes, you have to insert different values.

Answer (score 0):

The result of dereferencing your `pos` iterator is a `pair<ShapeType, vector<Shape*>>&`, so its `second` member is a `vector<Shape*>` - in other words, you need to iterate through all elements of each value in the map, e.g.,

```
for (auto& kv : shapeMap)
{
    for (auto shape : kv.second)
    {
        shape->Draw();
    }
}
```